# JOIN four tables to create an restaurant menustructure

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have four tables I would like to join to the tables in the picture below

[image: Database]

This is what i have come up with for now:

```
        SELECT 
            category.category_id,
            category.name,
            menuitems.name AS menu_name,
            restaurant.restaurant_id
        FROM 
            category
        JOIN
            restaurant_has_category
        ON
            category.category_id = restaurant_has_category.category_id
        AND
            restaurant_has_category.category_id = category.category_id
        JOIN
            restaurant
        JOIN
            menuitems
```

The result is this:

[image: Result]

As you can see I'm getting duplicates and the query thinks that the category name and menuItem name aren't distinct. I would love to show which categories a restaurant have AND then I would love to show all the different menuItems in each category

In the writing of this I realise that I need a separate query for all my menuItems ?

Can you see what im going for ? and my problem?

AS REQUESTED HERE IS THE CODE instead of pictures

```
     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
 `category_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `description` MEDIUMTEXT,
 `image` VARCHAR(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
 );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `restaurant` (
 `restaurant_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
 `description` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
 `image` VARCHAR(255),
 `URL` VARCHAR(255),
`email` VARCHAR(100),
 `openingHours` VARCHAR(255),
 `CVR` INT(45),
`telephone` INT(45),
 `place_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`restaurant_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`place_id`) REFERENCES place(`place_id`)
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `restaurant_has_category` (
 `restaurant_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `category_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`restaurant_id`, `category_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) REFERENCES restaurant(`restaurant_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES category(`category_id`)
  );

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menuItems` (
 `menuItems_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 `toppings` VARCHAR(250),
 `price` INT(10) NOT NULL,
 `size` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `category_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`menuItems_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES category(`category_id`)
 );
```

Here are som sample data to play around with;

```
 INSERT INTO `menuitems` (`menuItems_id`, `name`, `toppings`, `price`, 
 `size`, `category_id`) VALUES
 (1, 'Margherita', 'Tomatsovs, Ost', 55, '1pers', 1),
 (4, 'Cheese Burger', 'Ost, salat, oksebøf', 89, '', 3),
 (7, 'Durum rulle', 'Kebab, salat, tomat, agurk, skinke', 67, '', 2);

 INSERT INTO `category` (`category_id`, `name`, `description`, `image`) 
 VALUES
 (1, 'Pizza', 'beskrivelse', 'foto'),
 (2, 'Ruller', 'beskrivelse', 'foto'),
 (3, 'Burger', 'beskivelse', 'foto');

 INSERT INTO `restaurant_has_category` (`restaurant_id`, `category_id`) 
 VALUES
 (2, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (2, 3);

  INSERT INTO `restaurant` (`restaurant_id`, `name`, `description`, `image`, 
  `URL`, `email`, `openingHours`, `CVR`, `telephone`, `place_id`) VALUES
  (2, 'Alforno Pizza', 'Lorem ipsum dolor, description text here', 
   'https://migogkbh.dk/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Kiin-Kiin-Bao-Bao-Foto- 
  Rasmus-Schou.jpg', 'hjemmeside', 'email@email.com', 'mo - th: 09:00', 0, 
  11223344, 1);
```

THIS IS THE FORMAT I'M SEEKING

category_id | category.name |   menu_name   | restaurant_id

---

```
 1            Pizza        Margherita          2
```

---

```
 1            Pizza       Kebab pizza          2
```

---

```
 2            Burger       Kebab burger        2
```

---

```
 2            Burger       Cheese burger       2
```

---

```
 3            Durum         kebab              2
```

Comment: Those rows have no duplicates.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the wanted result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: BTW, why do you have the same `category.category_id = restaurant_has_category.category_id` condition twice?

Comment: Yea, okay i see now that its overkill now.

Comment: I've editted the data now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting duplication and misinformation because restaurant and menuitems are cross-joined to each other and the other tables.  Fix your FROM clause and you will get the data you expect.

You can find basic SQL tutorials all over the web.  My favorite beginner SQL training is at W3CSchools.com.  But don't stop there.  You should also try to understand set relationships and how those are defined in terms of SQL code.  I find presentations that use Venn diagrams can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I see now. I've been stairing blank into the code! Thank you for the feedback.